# Adding multiple values to a Table in SQL using a trigger and audit table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The issue I am having is when I insert more than one value into a table or delete a value that exists more than once in a table. I am unsure how to work around this issue.

```
`CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Q5Trigger]
 ON [dbo].[WF]
 AFTER INSERT, DELETE
 AS
 IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'AuditTable')
    BEGIN
     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditTable](
     Word         VARCHAR(100),
     Frequency    INT,
     Date         DATETIME,
     Type         VARCHAR(100)
     )
 END
 IF EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM inserted) 
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO AuditTable VALUES((SELECT Word  FROM inserted),(SELECT Frequency  FROM inserted), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Inserted')
 END
 IF EXISTS (SELECT *  FROM deleted) 
    BEGIN
     INSERT INTO AuditTable VALUES((SELECT Word  FROM deleted),(SELECT Frequency  FROM deleted), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Deleted')
 END`
```

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how triggers and INSERTED and DELETED work. When you insert 50 records into a table with a trigger, the trigger gets called once and the INSERTED table has 50 records in it. To do what you are doing, you must insert into the 1 table ALL the records of the other table.

```
INSERT INTO AuditTable (Word,Frequency,LogWhen,LogType)
SELECT Word,Frequency, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Inserted' FROM inserted
```

Your delete would be very similar to this.